# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/New file.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I've been trying to encrypt files and write those files back on to the same place. But I got the error message saying `"java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/New file.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)".`

My `Manifest` file is this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tdk.mytestapplication2">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
```

I think I have provided correct permission there. And the code I am using to encrypt files is this.

```
public static void encrypt(SecretKey secretKey, String filePath){
    try {
        // Here you read the cleartext.
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

        // Create cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }

        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(InvalidKeyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I used this method inside a button

```
Button btnEncrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnc);
    btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            aesKey = EncAndDec.generateKey();
            String filePath = editText.getText().toString();
            //Generating the file hash
            String md5Hash = MD5Hash.getMD5(filePath);

            System.out.println(aesKey.toString());
            System.out.println(filePath);
            System.out.println(md5Hash);

            //Encrypting the file
            for(int i=1; i<100; i++) {
                EncAndDec.encrypt(aesKey, filePath);
            }
        }
    });
```

Still I couldn't configure this error. Please someone help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: Please also confirm:  does the file `/storage/emulated/0/New file.txt:` exist? Do you see it when you browse through your device?

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla hmmm since the message is "Permission Denied" then the file do exist(if it didn't the message would be "file not found")

Comment: The thing is your error includes `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/New file.txt...`, hence I am asking if you have confirmed that the file does exist - in which case the error might be misleading. But things seem strange in your case, because you declared permissions yet you still get `Permission Denied` - so please cross check that the file itself is there.

Comment: @Tharindu What version of Android are you running?

Comment: @Bryan my API is 23 Android 6.0 Marshmallow and now downgraded to 19 which is KITKAT

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla the file is there I can access it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I suspect you are running Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23) or later. If this is the case, you *must* implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) before you try to read/write external storage.

Comment: ... only if the target SDK is 23 or higher

Comment: My target SDK is 19 but emulator is 23

Comment: @Tharindu Hm, as @devnull69 mentioned, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 22 or lower, then it should still use the old permissions model. This might not be the issue.

Comment: @Bryan still installing some components right after installed them I'll give a try to run and update here

Comment: @Bryan do you have any samples for building runtime permissions I'm new to android development

Comment: @Tharindu The developer website has a pretty good [Runtime Permissions Sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/RuntimePermissions/project.html) application.

Comment: @Bryan I have downgraded to android APK 19 KitKat and now its working fine. Thank you for the help

Comment: How about for instrumentation tests?  Can we use **adb shell pm grant** [permission]?

Comment: @Tharindu, have you ever find a solution to this? If yes, you can post a separate answer for this.

Comment: @Hemang The solution is as stated above; if your target SDK is level 23 or higher, you must implement runtime permissions. Otherwise, you only need to declare the permission in your `Manifest.xml` file

Answer (score 143):

If you are running in Android 29 then you have to use scoped storage or for now, you can bypass this issue by using:

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

in manifest in the application tag.

Comment: You really saved me but I still having issues on android 5

Comment: I think you need to check your permissions @IslamAssem

Comment: can't believe they putted false by default... what a joke i spent 2 hours on it

Comment: You made my day, thanks for this answer :-)

Comment: It's works but, is it a temporary solution? I already added manifest permissions and use in app permissions and still need legacy permission... It's feels wrong.

Comment: This is strange but after adding this line (along with runtime permission of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) , now i am able to see ExternalRootDirectory path earlier it was coming as undefined, 
 still when I open directory reader it shows 0 count, any suggestion ?  look like , running with Android30 API same issue is with 29

Comment: @Dharmesh Did u add Read Permission?

Comment: @Prabhat Rai  Read + write_ext_storege both the permission are there

Comment: This solution is temporary and won't work on Android 11. You have to use MediaStore class. Check this link for the permanent solution. https://sujeetkumargpt06.medium.com/storage-access-in-android-11-and-above-scoped-storage-8dc439e87441

Comment: I worked for many hours, this is the only fix that worked.  I never had an issue with saving file before.

Answer (score 24):

Implement runtime permission for running your app on Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23) or later.

or you can manually enable the storage permission-

goto settings>apps> "your_app_name" >click on it >then click permissions> then enable the storage. Thats it.

But i suggest go the for first one which is, Implement runtime permissions in your code.

Comment: Actually the second suggestion is much better if you just need to save some stuff for debug purposes.

Comment: yes, it can be used for debug purpose @ŁukaszSromek

Comment: what about for android11.0 or higher any idea ?

Answer (score 16):

On Android 11, apps can no longer access files in any other app's dedicated, app-specific directory within external storage.
To protect user privacy, on devices that run Android 11 or higher, the system further restricts your app's access to other apps' private directories.

**Request MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
```

**Request External Storage Permissions**

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,
new String[]{
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
}, 1
);
```

**Checking permission of MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

```
// If you have access to the external storage, do whatever you need
if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){

// If you don't have access, launch a new activity to show the user the system's dialog
// to allow access to the external storage
}else{
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
  Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
  intent.setData(uri);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: avoid using  MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE , your app may not get accepted in play store

Comment: would add: also consider migrate to scoped storage to avoid this risky MANAGE permission

Comment: what to do my app also rejected by playstore for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 2):

For SDK 29 :

```
String str1 = "";
folder1 = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)));
if (folder1.exists()) {str1 = folder1.toString() + File.separator;}

public static void createTextFile(String sBody, String FileName, String Where) {
    try {
        File gpxfile = new File(Where, FileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then you can save your file like this :

```
createTextFile("This is Content","file.txt",str1);
```