# ERROR : onRequestPermissionsResult: prepare() failedjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/audio.3gp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, runtime-error, filenotfoundexception, mediarecorder

I am developing a audio recorder app using [Media recorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder) for android(java). Here, I have to set the path of the audio file using the [SetOutputFile()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setOutputFile(java.io.FileDescriptor)). I did try a few codes to set the file output path but none worked, and I got the above mentioned error in logcat

Here is the code I used to set output file location:

```
String path;
 path = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 path+="/audio.3gp";
```

Here is my code on the onclick where I used most of MediaRecorder's methods:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
                if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE)) {
                    mediarec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Mic present",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                mediarec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mediarec.setOutputFile(path);
                mediarec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                try {
                    mediarec.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: prepare() failed" + e);
                }
                mediarec.start();
            }
        };
        start.setOnClickListener(myonclick);
```

Here are the set of permissions I asked in android manifest(and I also asked for the runtime permission in mainactivity):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is the error shown in logcat:

```
E/Main Activity: onRequestPermissionsResult: prepare() failedjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/audio.3gp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E/MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Can someone guide me how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cross check with manifest,you must take permission of `RECORD_AUDIO`

Comment: Yes I did take the permission, Just edited the post to add the permissions code too

Comment: did you try this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819550/java-io-filenotfoundexception-storage-emulated-0-new-file-txt-open-failed-ea?rq=1

Comment: @EAS Yes, I did checked it and it did not help